# Question on communication between universes in a level 1 multiverse

Tags: energy, information, multiverse

Can matter, energy, or information travel from one universe to another in a [Level I Multiverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse#Level_I%3a_Beyond_our_cosmological_horizon)? That is, is there any communication between Hubble volumes in an eternal inflation-induced multiverse?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no by definition, since [level 1 universes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse#Level_I%3a_Beyond_our_cosmological_horizon) are separated by a cosmological horizon. If they weren't separated by a horizon they wouldn't be seperate level 1 universes.

It's a general feature of separate universes that they are causally disconnected. It's the fact of causal disconnection that makes us treat them as separate.

Comment: so according to this and what we know you're saying that it's not possible for any kind of matter,energy or information travel between any universes right? (i don't know why but i feel a little bit happy bout this)